# thumbnails not lining up

Tags: jquery, html, css, youtube-api

I am trying to paste a youtube api feed onto this page but the thumbnails are not lining up properly. The working site can be found [here](http://netx.clanteam.com/vs/video.html).

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Inner page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main_block">
 <div id="innerblock">


                 <!--Top Panel starts here -->

        <div id="top_panel">


                <a href="index.html" class="logo"><img src="images/logo.jpg" width="255" height="36" alt="" /></a><br />

            <div class="tp_navbg">
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                <a href="inner.html">Upload</a>
                <a href="#">Videos</a>
                <a href="#">Channels</a>
                <a href="#">News</a>
            </div>

            <div class="tp_smlgrnbg">
                <span class="tp_sign"><a href="#" class="tp_txt">Sign Up</a>
                <span class="tp_divi">|</span>
                <a href="#" class="tp_txt">Login</a>
                <span class="tp_divi">|</span>
                <a href="#" class="tp_txt">Help</a></span>
            </div>

            <div class="tp_barbg">
                <input name="#" type="text" class="tp_barip" />
                <select name="#" class="tp_drp"><option>Videos</option></select>
                <a href="#" class="tp_search"><img src="images/tp_search.jpg" width="52" height="24" alt="" /></a>
                <span class="tp_welcum">Welcome <b>Guest</b></span>

            </div>

        </div>





                <span class="lp_newvidit1">Video Title</span>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="files/style6.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/jquery-1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("body").append("<div id = 'data'><ul>.</ul></div>");
        var dataContainer = $("#data ul");
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/googledevelopers/uploads?max-results=50&time=today&alt=jsonc&v=2&callback=?',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data){

                     $.each(data.data.items, 
                               function(i, val) {

                                 if (typeof(val.player) !== 'undefined' && typeof(val.title) !== 'undefined') {

                                    dataContainer.append('<div class="d e"><a href='+val.player["default"]+' target="_blank" title="'+val.title+'">'+val.title+'</a><br /><img src="'+val.thumbnail.sqDefault+'" width="120" height="90" alt="'+val.title+'"/><br />Views '+val.viewCount+'</div>');
                                 }
                         });
                    }
                });
            });

</script>
```

The thumbnails line up otherwise. Like [here](http://netx.clanteam.com/test.html)
The thumbnails line up otherwise.....

Comment: looks OK. What browser are you looking at?

Comment: fine in chrome. [but in firefox its mis-aligned](http://i.imgur.com/7ueJXjx.jpg)

Comment: Add `vertical-align: top;` to `<div class="d e" />` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing two closing tags `</div>` try adding them at the end of the document just before `</body>` closing tag and change this:

```
$("body").append("<div id = 'data'><ul>.</ul></div>");
```

to this:

```
$("#main_block").append("<div id = 'data'><ul>.</ul></div>");
```

add this css property:

```
#data{
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

move the scripts and stylesheets links including the jquery script to the head section and put them after the `<title></title>` tag, this would let the document load those scripts first before loading the body which will improve the performance and prevent potential problems.

Comment: It corrects the problem to an extent but the top bar is still mis-aligned. like [here](http://i.imgur.com/T0xEOGs.jpg).  I added the </div> tags and edited the line mentioned in your post.

Comment: upload your updated website on the server and share a link so that i can have a look, or just add the CSS script here.

Comment: what's messed up? it looks fine for me!

Comment: I am viewing it on firefox and this is [what I get.](http://i.imgur.com/rgiuXld.jpg)

Comment: yah it's pretty messed up on firefox, add `float: left` to `#data`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this to your css

```
#data ul{padding-top: 240px;}
```

Also it looks like you are missing 2 end div tags when I use view-source, not sure if thats whats causing misalignment.

Comment: it's most likely the reason of the misalignment becuase the `data` div would be placed inside the `innerblock` otherwise